# getConversionRate() returns a 0

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, smart-contract-wallets

I'm trying to get getConversionRate() to return an ETH value for 100 by running this script:

```
from brownie import Donation, config, network, MockV3Aggregator

from scripts.helpful_scripts import (
    LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS,
    deploy_mocks,
    get_account,
)


def deploy_donation():
    account = get_account()

    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        price_feed_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()][
            "eth_usd_price_feed_address"
        ]
    else:
        deploy_mocks()
        price_feed_address = MockV3Aggregator[-1].address
    donation = Donation.deploy(
        price_feed_address,
        {"from": account},
    )
    print(f"Contract deployed to {donation.address}")
    get_price = donation.getPrice()
    print(f"The current price of ETH/USD is {get_price}")
    get_conversion_rate = donation.getConversionRate(100)
    print(get_conversion_rate)
    return donation


def main():
    deploy_donation()
```

for this smart contract:

```
// SPDX-LIcense-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract Donation {
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;

    uint256 ethAmount;
    address payable owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;

    constructor(address _priceFeed) public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function donate(uint256 _amount) public payable {
        ethAmount = getConversionRate(_amount);
        owner.transfer(ethAmount);
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint256 rawUSD) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethValue = (rawUSD / ethPrice) * 1000000000000000000;
        return ethValue;
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }
}
```

Please what is the problem with my script, how do i get it to return a converted value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solidity there are no fractions. So for example: `1/2` will get rounded down to 0.

In your script, you calculate `rawUSD / ethPrice`. Since `rawUSD` is only 100, and `ethPrice` is probably larger, this gets rounded down to 0.

This is why in Solidity you should always do multiplication  before division.

So if you change your line to:

`uint256 ethValue = rawUSD * 1000000000000000000 / ethPrice;`

You should be able to get a result.

*Note: I didn't check the correctness of the decimal calculation which might be a different issue. Also, you can write `1e18` or `1 ether` instead of `1000000000000000000` to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks so much! i had to changed my getPrice() to get it to work. function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer / 100000000);
    }